# What can be done with the [region] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [region](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/region) tag has:

387 questions tagged. (103 are unanswered)

doesn't have the best wiki:

```
Can refer to many different things depending on the use of other tags with it.
```

and is used in conjunction with other tags ranging from C# to mapkit to Android.

I've used this tag for a couple of my questions, however with the tag wiki so vague I don't think it helps clarify them.

Are these sort of tags burninated or cleaned up? I don't see a way to clean the wiki so that it covers all the topics it's used in.

Comment: Tags should ideally have *one meaning*. Any tag that has multiple meanings should be replaced by more specific, focused tags.

Comment: If we clean up [tag:region], take out [tag:regions] too.

Comment: [These tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199462/burninate-request-countries-city) were mentioned in a MSE post. We have very broad tags like [countries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/countries), [country](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/country), [city](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/city), etc

Comment: @MartijnPieters if cleaning the tag is the way to go, how can I help?  Do you delete low voted questions and remove the tag from questions that look like they can do without it.

Comment: @bluefeet looks like there needs to be a major clean up of all of them. I'm surprised they haven't been turned into synonyms of each other yet.

Comment: @Gurfuffle: You replace or remove the tag from all posts; if the tag might actually carry meaning for a post, you find or create a tag with a better, more focused meaning.